# Reuse angular module from another project

Tags: angular, azure, azure-pipelines, devops

I have two projects internal and external. in which internal project is completed and now we are going to implement external project. In internal project we have one (test) module, we need to reuse the same module in external project also. I tried importing in external project app.module.ts file, In local it is working fine but while deploying it is failing because it can not find the path. We are using azure to deploy the project.

{
path : 'test',
loadChildren: () => import('../../../internal/src/app/test/test.module').then(m => m.TestModule)
}

**project structure**

[image]

Comment: Please check [Sharing Components Between Angular Applications](https://codeburst.io/sharing-components-between-angular-applications-using-bit-707654263785) and [Sharing modules](https://angular.io/guide/sharing-ngmodules)

Comment: I am stuck on this issue too , Did you find the answer